# Javascript animations in jQuery using transform.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

i'm performing some animations with transitions using the plugin demo'd here http://www.binpress.com/app/demo/app/145

However i'm using multiple transitions on the same element.

Basically i have an animation with 5 circles working as satellite objects around a central point. The central point has a little arrow and as you hover over any of the satellite points it transforms using this plugin to the satellite circle being hovered over.

Here's an example of what i'm doing, simplified.

```
jQuery(".applications").bind('mouseover', function(){
    console.log('fired the second animation');  
    jQuery(".midpointer").animate({
        transform: 'rotate(190deg)'
    }); 
});


jQuery(".hosting").bind('mouseover', function(){
    console.log('fired the second animation');  
    jQuery(".midpointer").animate({
        transform: 'rotate(190deg)'
    }); 
});
```

Now the problem with this, is that after the first animation any subsequent hovers do not rotate the element. So i'm assuming I need to do some form of reset, I had been looking at .stop() in jQuery but to little avail.

Anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you rotate 190deg from the starting position each time you do a mouse over, not relative to the current rotation of the object. 
According to the documentation, you can use `+=` to add to the current rotation:
`transform: '+=rotate(190deg)'`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion however, after the first movement, the object will not move at all for some reason. Something must need to be done to clear the object before another animation can be performed.